# How to handle huge amount of events for a real time application?

Tags: c#, sql, web, asp.net-core, queue

I couldn't find a good title for this question. Sorry for that. I try to explain it with an example. We are thinking about this a long time now, but we are not sure how to do it.

I am developing with some friends a web application where users can execute actions and they will take place sometime in the future. Our goal is it, to always provide 100% fresh data over our api. Our idea was to build our application in 3 parts. The Api (for the actions), the frontend (maybe nodejs, only showing information) and workers (n amount, scaleable / probably C# .NET Core application).

Example:
User1 executes Action 'A' over the API => server calculates execute time, it should be executed at 14:00 o'clock.

We have now the following problem. What if 10000 users execute 200 actions that should take place on 14:00 o'clock? (Some events have dependencies on each other, the reason why async gets difficult). Of course the workers can handle the events, but how do we ensure that a request over the API all the time has fresh data?

I got the idea that the users send requests to the api and get a OK + a event id back. The Api handles the request and sends an result response over a websocket connection back to the user. But how do we ensure that it won't take longer than a usual api call. It has to be real time for the users, so it has to be scaleable.

We had a look into RabbitMQ for example, but this can't fit our criteria because we have to ensure that NO data gets lost or stuck.
(P.s. We know that we have to provide a solid database structure for this amount of events => we created a big mysql cluster for this)

I hope someone finds a way to give some ideas.
Feel free to ask questions if it helps you to answer my question. :)

Greets,
TheMrone

Comment: I could have what you are saying all wrong (wouldn't be the first time I've misread a question) but, "fresh data" is a point-in-time thing. You can only furnish the data that you have in the db at any given point in time. If you have pending transactions that will alter the data once processed, you can only provide that altered data after the processing occurs. So, technically, "fresh data" is whatever is currently in your db when the call for data comes in. And, don't quote me on this because I'm certainly no expert on Nodejs, but I think Nodejs is server side not client side (front end).

Comment: @Kevin Yes, I know this but how could we do this? An idea?

Comment: @Kevin With NodeJs I mean it provides the compiled react stuff. :)